# Error in creating generic DefaultKafkaProducerFactory in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am writing Kafka Consumer where I need to provide handling of DeserializationException for incorrect message. I am using error handling along with DLQ. I referred spring documentation to create KafkaTemplate for handling of both normal java object as well as raw bytes.

```
ref. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer
```

I am getting error while building the project. it is because of Raw use of parameterized class 'DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>'.
Can anyone please help on resolution?

```
  public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig(), new StringSerializer(),
        new DelegatingByTypeSerializer(Map.of(byte[].class, new ByteArraySerializer(),
           Employee.class, new JsonSerializer<>())));
  }



@Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
  }
```

error:

```
cannot infer type arguments for org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>
```

Comment: What's your spring boot and kafka version ?

Comment: Hi Mathew, Spring boot : 2.7.3, kafka: 3.2.0